# How to write GET api into existing files in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, get

I'm trying to get some basic data from 2 different web api's (battery status and contacs) and write it into my .txt file

However when i do that, only one data gets written, as if it overwrites the other.

I know my code may look really bad, but im new to this and i really need help.

**Code**

```
//GET - Battery status
var options = {
    host: 'www.w3.org',
    port: 80,
    path: '/work'
};

http.get(options, function (response) {
    console.log("Response: " + response.statusCode);
    console.log("Header:" + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
    fs.writeFile("external-api.txt", "Responsecode:" + response.statusCode + "\nHeaders:" + JSON.stringify(response.headers))       
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Napaka!: " + e.message);
});

//GET ZAHTEVE - Contacts
var options = {
    host: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/work'
};

http.get(options, function (response) {
    console.log("Odgovor: " + response.statusCode);
    console.log("Header:" + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
    fs.writeFile("external-api.txt", "Responsecode:" + response.statusCode + "\nHeaders:" + JSON.stringify(response.headers))
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Napaka!: " + e.message);
});
```

**Result**
[image]

Anyone kind enough to tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback):

> `fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)`
>
> Asynchronously writes data to a file, **replacing the file if it already exists**. data can be a string or a buffer.

So,what you're looking for is:

> `fs.appendFile(file, data[, options], callback)`
>
> Asynchronously append data to a file, creating the file if it does not
> yet exist. data can be a string or a buffer.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you thank you thank you very much! works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use fs.appendFile .

```
 fs.appendFile('message.txt', 'data to append', function (err) {

});
```